# In docker-compose, what is the effect/purpose of `dns-search: .`

Tags: docker-compose

I am looking at the [stackstorm docker-compose file](https://github.com/StackStorm/st2-docker/blob/a6aa05c890005eb2ddc87253c2ac42a62a078469/docker-compose.yml), and within it almost all containers have a [line](https://github.com/StackStorm/st2-docker/blob/a6aa05c890005eb2ddc87253c2ac42a62a078469/docker-compose.yml#L33) `dns_search: .` According to docker-compose documentation, `dns_search` is for the purpose of [configuring search domains](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#dns_search).

I am used to seeing this in context of transparently adding a domain to unqualified short domains. For example if I add `dns_search: mydomain.com`, I would expect "host1" to transparently resolve as "host1.mydomain.com".

I have never seen this set as a single dot `.` before. What is the effect/purpose of doing this configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm posting the answer from the Stackstorm Git project issue [see comment/"dns_search: ."](https://github.com/StackStorm/st2-docker/issues/231#issuecomment-983990107). Paraphrasing: it was useful in old versions of Docker before 2017, before the `ndots` configuration was available. Nowadays that configuration has no impact, and in fact has been removed from the stackstorm docker-compose file.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because all domain names end in . under the hood, but browsers and other software abstracts this out.

For example. under the hood `www.google.com` is actually `www.google.com.`

So, in the docker-compose file, this would essentially be saying "Find me any domain"

A bit more detail on why there's an extra dot, if you're interested:

Domain name resolution is heirachical, reading right to left, with each block, separated by a `.`, being a step in the process. A DNS resolver will first find a source of `.`, which will be able to return the address for a resolver for the next block, until it reaches the final block, where it returns the full DNS record.

Answer (score 0):

Extending [EdwardTeach's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70429028/7365866):

[@ytjohn effectively said](https://github.com/StackStorm/st2-docker/issues/231#issuecomment-983990107) they did in the past because putting `dns_search: .` configures the DNS search domains to be only `.` instead of inheriting the host ones. I can't confirm that because I didn't test it.

**Now,** I tested what docker-compose does today, and in a container, `cat /etc/resolve.conf` returns:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```

Where `options ndots:0` is (from [resolv.conf](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolv.conf.5.html) docs):

> **ndots:n**
> Sets a **threshold** for the number of dots which must
> appear in a name given to res_query(3) (see
> resolver(3)) **before an initial absolute query will
> be made**.  The default for n is 1, meaning that if
> there are any dots in a name, the name will be
> tried first as an absolute name before any search
> list elements are appended to it.  The value for
> this option is silently capped to 15.

With `ndots:0`, **all** domains will be attempted using the absolute name first, **only then using the search list**.

---

How I came to this conclusion

The Github comment:

> If you don't set this `dns_search: .`, then whatever the host has in search in their `/etc/resolv.conf` will get put into your container's /etc/resolv.conf.

This doesn't happen. My host has `search domain[0]: broadband` (macOS command: `scutil --dns`), and in docker containers, it doesn't show broadband (linux command: `cat /etc/resolv.conf`). Instead, it says `options ndots:0`

- `dns_search` docs:

> dns defines custom DNS search domains to set on container network interface configuration. Can be a single value or a list.

- What is a DNS search domain?

It is the DNS service used to resolve hostnames that are not fully qualified, e.g. `hostname` will try `hostname.example.com` then `hostname.website.com` if your `search domains list` was `example.com, website.com`. More information on https://superuser.com/a/184366

- In another repo ([crossdock](https://github.com/crossdock/crossdock)), their dockerfile had the comment:

```
`dns_search: .  # Ensures unified DNS config.`
```